# Statistical Significnace of a Survey Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, descriptive-statistics, normalization

We understand that the bigger the sample size, the more reliable is the result of the data analysis of a survey. How do you determine with confidence that a survey results are valid and representative of the population?

We can create boxplots to check for outliers or histograms to see if the sample is normal. What other preliminary statistical checks are necessary?

Comment: First, one should try to run a 'power and sample size' procedure to ensure large enough samples. Random sampling (perhaps within strata) from the population should be the next step. Later one might check various demographic features (age, income, gender, race, etc.) of the sample against known demographic characteristics of the population. If not in agreement, some re-weighting might be in order. // Checking for normality seems pointless unless it is known that the population is normal.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you determine with confidence that a survey results are valid and representative of the population?

Well, you see, you can't just *check* this is the case.  Let me explain.

A very pervasive problem in surveys is known as *non-response bias*.  People unfortunately do not like to respond to surveys, and those who do respond are all alike in some way (my guess is that they are all older, white, middle class citizens but I could be wrong). No statistical procedure -- in the absence of any information towards the existence of this bias -- is capable of detecting it.  This bias threatens the validity of the survey.

Even if you were to ask for things like Socioeconomic status, race, age, etc., there could always be *one more variable* you forgot to account for which threatens the validity through this bias.  That being said, if you're willing to make assumptions about which variables effect this non-response, you could attempt [post-stratification](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/poststratification).